# Is it possible to target CSS3 columns individually with selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors, multiple-columns

The design I am working to has different backgrounds for alternate columns. Is it possible to set up different tiling backgrounds for each column,

e.g.

```
column:nth-child(n+1) {background:url(tile1.gif) repeat-x; }
```

Or do I have to fall back on a huge background image that tiles every two columns?

Comment: Do you mean `column:nth-child(even)` and `column:nth-child(odd)`?

Comment: I don't believe so, but +1 for adding this to the W3C's draft.

Comment: @JulesMazur: It will be pretty difficult to implement as a selector though (`::nth-column()` pseudo-element?), especially given how it's currently specced in the Multi-column Layout module. `column:nth-...` can't be used because `column` is supposed to target a `<column>` element, and there's no guarantee that won't exist in HTML5 or doesn't exist in any other language (plus there's already a `<col>` for tables).

Comment: Good point. Suppose this could be done by putting divs so as to have each column occupied by a single div, and select those?

Comment: @JulesMazur, you'd have no way of controlling whether your div would end with each column, and your divs wouldn't necessarily stretch to fit each column either :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot change the color of the columns:

> It is not possible to set properties/values on column boxes. For example, the background of a certain column box cannot be set and a column box has no concept of padding, margin or borders.

From w3.org: [2. The multi-column model](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#the-multi-column-model)

Comment: It does also say, "Future specifications may add additional functionality. For example, columns of different widths and different backgrounds may be supported." For those who want to hope.