# css webkit column access to single column

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, webkit

I have multi-column layout using -webkit-column-* properties.

Is it possible to specify css rules for some specific column? Or better, I would like to have columns wrapped in div element, so I could access them via javascript.

This is for iOS so only -webkit* solution would be OK.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, see http://w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp for the available selectors.

Comment: I also think so. Perhaps I need to use some javascript based approach, like columnizer plugin, although it seems it does not work as well as css -webkit-column* does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to target CSS3 columns individually with selectors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189229/is-it-possible-to-target-css3-columns-individually-with-selectors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I do not believe this is possible (though it probably should be).

This question was asked in a similar manner here: [Is it possible to target CSS3 columns individually with selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13189229/1871799)

You can take a look a the WC's Multi-Column Recommendation here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/

I would look for a javascript solution.