# Last-of-column selector for css columns

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to find a selector anywhere to do what I'm looking for. I have a CSS column layout (using `column-count:3`), and a variable amount of divs in the layout (so I can't just use a regular `nth-child()` rule. I have a border underneath each div, but I would like the bottom div from each column to forego the border (no need for a separator on the bottom of each column, and since they're uneven I don't think it looks very good). Is there a selector that would get the bottom div of each column?

Comment: what is the dom structure ? can you try and reproduce your issue in a fiddle ?

Comment: No such selector exists since the `column` is not an element by itself but rather a style.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to target CSS3 columns individually with selectors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189229/is-it-possible-to-target-css3-columns-individually-with-selectors)

Comment: Actually, [how to target last-child in a CSS3 column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22091648/how-to-target-last-child-in-a-css3-column) looks like a closer duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I propose an alternative solution for the specific `border` problem:

How about move the border on top of the div?
I noticed the first column's item ignore the margin.
If the columns wrapper has `overflow:hidden;` you can hide the border with negative top position.

```css
.columns-wrapper{ padding:1rem;}
.columns{
  column-count:3;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.column-item{
  break-inside: avoid;
  border-top:1px solid #ff0000;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  top: calc(-1px - 1rem);
}
.column-item+.column-item{padding-top:1rem;}
```

```html
<div class="columns-wrapper">
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="column-item">item 1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="column-item">item 2 consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
    <div class="column-item">item 3 Donec euismod felis at sapien malesuada eleifend</div>
    <div class="column-item">item 4 Suspendisse interdum</div>
    <div class="column-item">item 5 orci non scelerisque tempus</div>
    <div class="column-item">item 6 velit nibh gravida ipsum, non vestibulum quam mi eu enim.</div>
    <div class="column-item">item 7 Nulla in quam dapibus</div>
    <div class="column-item">item 8 viverra arcu et</div>
    <div class="column-item">item 9 maximus risus</div>
    <div class="column-item">item 10 Maecenas et nunc enim.</div>
    <div class="column-item">item 11</div>
  </div>
</div>
```