# change the background-color of columns only

Tags: css

Hi I would like to change the background color of the columns only, If I use the tradtional property that changes the whole background!
What I whant is only the columns background color to change.

Here is my CSS code

```
.multiple_columns-line1{
       text-align: justify;
       column-count: 3;
       column-gap: 45px;
       column-rule-style: double;
       column-rule-width: 10px;
       column-rule-color: darkmagenta;
       background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

Can anyone solve this mystery please?

Comment: Please be specific. column background of what? you mean a table?

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML code.  AFAIK the `background-color` CSS property applies to DOM elements, not "columns" of elements.

Comment: This is a simple paragraph divided to 3 columns, If I change the background color it changes for the whole element, what I whant is change the background color only for the columns (like in a newspaper, the main background is white and the columns background is lightgray) for an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still today, early 2017, we can't do that with a column property, so for the ones who really need it, here is one workaround.

*This post, [`Is it possible to target CSS3 columns individually with selectors?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189229/is-it-possible-to-target-css3-columns-individually-with-selectors), might be a duplicate, though I decided to not close it as such, as the below solution might be a valid answer*

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.newspaper {
  column-count: 3;
  text-align: justify;
  column-gap: 45px;
  column-rule-style: double;
  column-rule-width: 10px;
  column-rule-color: darkmagenta;
}
.bgcolor,
.bgcolor::before,
.bgcolor::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(33% - 5px);
  background-color: lightgreen;
  z-index: -1;
}
.bgcolor {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.bgcolor::before {
  left: calc(-100% - 15px);
  width: calc(100% - 7px);
}
.bgcolor::after {
  right: calc(-100% - 15px);
  width: calc(100% - 7px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="bgcolor"></div>
  <div class="newspaper">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex
    ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit
    augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think that post is a duplicate. The asker here only seems interested in styling all the columns, not individual ones. When you originally posted your answer there, I was about to ask how it was relevant because you weren't trying to target individual columns in any way.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks, was simply referring to the fact that one can't style columns at all ... and I missed the _target individual column_ part :)